# kurento-tutorial-js: No remote stream shown in hello-world example

Tags: kurento

I'm new to Kurento and decided to start getting into it by running all of the tutorials provided. But unfortunately when I already run the kurento-hello-world tutorial there is no remote stream shown, always just the loading screen and the console also does not print out any errors. I'm using the docker image of Kurento and run the tutorial in another container that runs Ubuntu. I published the port of Kurento (8888) and at the Ubuntu I published the port 8443. I'm accessing the application by using the URL:

```
https://localhost:8443/index.html?ws_uri=wss://172.17.0.2:8888/kurento
```

where 172.17.0.2:8888 is the internal IP address of my docker container. Can somebody help with this? Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing the browser application, then you need to validate the certificate if you use an auto-generated one:

> Browser applications: You’ll need to manually accept the certificate
>   as trusted one before secure WebSocket connections can be established.
>   By default, this can be done by connecting to connecting to
>   https://localhost:8433/kurento and accepting the certificate in the
>   browser.

In your case, this would be https://172.17.0.2:8888/kurento.
Once this is done, you should see remote stream in your original url.

Best

Answer (score 0):

I open the chrome in windows system, and the remote stream be blocked by Firewall. First [Turn Windows Firewall off](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028544/windows-turn-windows-firewall-on-or-off) to exclude the Firewall problem.

holp this can help you.